# Move and Rename files using Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I have .xls files in a directory that i need to move to another directory and renamed.  Those files are updated monthly and will have a different name each month.  For instance the current name is **Geocortex Applications - Asset Capture - Sessions By Visitor Type (10_01_2018 - 10_06_2019).csv** and next month it will be **Geocortex Applications - Asset Capture - Sessions By Visitor Type (10_01_2018 - 11_06_2019).csv**  There are several of these files each with different names between the - - but the formatting is the same, see the image below.

[screen shot of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWSQS.png)

Each month i need those files moved to another folder and given the name that is between the - -.  For instance this one would need to be renamed **'Asset Capture.xls'**.

My python experience is limited...so far i've only used python within ESRI products using Arcpy.  Any help that can be given is greatly appreciated.

below is what i've done.  I can move a rename a single file but i need it to cycle through all xls and rename with the name between the - - in the file name.

```py
import shutil

import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\learly\Downloads')

renFolder= (r'C:\Users\learly\Downloads\renamed')

oldname = 'Geocortex Applications - Asset Capture - Sessions By Visitor Type 
(10_01_2018 - 10_06_2019).csv'

newname= 'renTest.csv'

shutil.move(oldname, renFolder+'/'+newname)
```

Comment: Have a look at [time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) and use the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) table to match/get which month you're in now or use date comparison methods to subtract and get the last month. You should also look at `os.stat(file_path).st_mtime` to determain when the files was last changed (like.. a month ago).

Comment: It's typically expected that you show some effort to solve the problem yourself and describe where exactly you got stuck. Otherwise it comes across as asking someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Running this will move all the files in your first folder to the second, and rename them:

```py
import os

ORIGINAL_FOLDER = "/path/to/your/original/folder/here/"
NEW_FOLDER = "/path/to/your/new/folder/here/"
for path in os.listdir(ORIGINAL_FOLDER): # all files in the folder
    if not path.endswith(".csv"):
         continue
    name = path.split("-")[1] # just the part we want
    # move the file to the new folder, and rename it
    os.rename(ORIGINAL_FOLDER + path,  NEW_FOLDER + name + ".xls")
```

You can either run this every month or set up some automatic way of doing it, like a cronjob.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `name = path.split("-")[1]`? OP said the name that is between the dashes.

Comment: When i run this i get an error....IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: One of your files must not have a dash in it, so `path.split("-")[1]` errors. Try `print(path)` to make sure you're giving it the correct directory.

Comment: I removed the items that did not have the dash and the error remains.

Comment: Is this because there is another dash later in the file name in the date?  If that is an issue then taking the file name before the date as the new file name would suffice.  Just trim off the date and whats left is the new file name. @tybug

Comment: Multiple dashes won't be an issue. Can you show the full output - not just the error - when you run my answer, including `print(path)` on the line below the for loop?

Comment: *** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
desktop.ini
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 7, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

This is with the print after the loop

Comment: Windows has some hidden files - `desktop.ini` is one of those files, and configures the appearance of the folder it's in. I've updated my answer to ignore this file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
import shutil

 for filename in os.listdir(ORIGINAL_FOLDER): # all files in the folder
    match = re.search(r"^Geocortex Applications - (.*)[(].*$", filename)
    shutil.move(f'{ORIGINAL_FOLDER}\\{filename}',  f'{NEW_FOLDER}\{match.group(1)}.xls')
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question