# Python: Find rename and move a JSON file from ADLS folder

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Very new to Python and Databricks in general. I've moved onto this platform from Data Factory.

I have a Databricks Notebook that queries an API and ultimately creates output files in a directory.

Those output files are the familiar "_committed.." and "_started.." files along with one .json file.

I'd like to be able to specify the folder that contains my data, find the name of the json file, move that file to another directory and rename it in the process.

I've been using code from this answer, but I think this will only really work on a local file system as it uses "os" - [Move and Rename files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238236/move-and-rename-files-using-python)

This is my broken code. It errors as it cant find the files/locations

```
import os

ORIGINAL_FOLDER = "/mnt/datalake/raw/Group/CompanyName/API/JSON/Campaign_Tags/"

NEW_FOLDER = "/mnt/datalake/cleansed/Group/CompanyName/API/JSON/Campaign_Tags/"

for path in os.listdir(ORIGINAL_FOLDER):  # all files in the folder

    if not path.endswith(".json"):

        continue

    name = "Campaign_Tags.json"

os.rename(ORIGINAL_FOLDER + path, NEW_FOLDER + name)
```

The ideal output would be the json rename to Campaign_tags.json in the "New Folder" directory on the ADLS

Answer (score 1):

To find and rename files from ADLS folder in databricks first you need to create mount points.

```py
dbutils.fs.mount(source = "wasbs://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/fsn2p",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net":"<access_key>"})
```

Then to list the file there is `dbutils` function in databricks by which you can list move, copy, list files in ADLS from databricks .

```py
ORIGINAL_FOLDER = "/mnt/fsn2p/demo1"
NEW_FOLDER = "/mnt/fsn2p/demo"

for fi in dbutils.fs.ls(ORIGINAL_FOLDER):  # all files in the folder
    if not fi.path.endswith(".json"):
        continue
    moved_file = fi.path.split("/")[-1]
    print(moved_file)
    
name = "Campaign_Tags.json"
dbutils.fs.mv(ORIGINAL_FOLDER + "/" + moved_file, NEW_FOLDER + "/" +name)
```

***sample input folder with Json file:***

[image]

***Output folder with renaming Json file:***

[image]

**Reference :** [Databricks Utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)